# How to set default value when creating a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to create the following and set is_seen to false explicitly.

```
rails g model notification body: text, user_id: integer, is_seen: boolean
```

I know how to update this alter via a change_column but how would I set this to false at this point?

This is not for a migration but from creating a model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I pass default value to rails generate migration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24565589/can-i-pass-default-value-to-rails-generate-migration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't set the default value while creating the model/migration at that point.**

You have to create/edit the migration file and change the corresponding line to something like this:

```
add_column :table, :is_seen, :boolean, default: false
```