# Rails t.array vs t.string array:true, default:[]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I am working with Rails 5 and POSTGRES and need to add an array column.  I have seen different syntax to do this.

What is the difference in migrations among..

```
t.string, :A_options array: true, default: []
```

and

```
t.integer, :A_options array: true, default: []
```

and

```
t.array, :A_options
```

Why specify the type as integer or string?  How are the first two different than the last?

Also, is there a way to add an array with default:[] using the rails generator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This creates an array of strings whose default is an empty array:

```
t.string :A_options, array: true, default: []
```

This creates an array of integers whose default is an empty array:

```
t.integer :A_options, array: true, default: []
```

This should be a `NoMethodError`:

```
t.array :A_options
```

There is no "array" type in PostgreSQL, only "array of X" where "X" is some other column type. PostgreSQL arrays aren't generic containers like Ruby arrays, they're more like arrays in C, C++, Go, ...

If you need a generic container that's more like a Ruby array then perhaps you want [`jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) instead. A `jsonb` array could hold a collection of numbers, strings, booleans, arrays, hashes, ... at the same time.

---

As far as the generator goes, you can't specify `default: []` because you [can't specify the `default` at all](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers):

> **3.5 Column Modifiers**
>   [...]
>
> > `null` and `default` cannot be specified via command line.

Also see [**Can I pass default value to rails generate migration?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24565589/479863).

Comment: I thought jsonb was for json, so would you need a key value pair. am I wrong?

Comment: You can directly encode an array in JSON, it isn't limited to JavaScript objects or Ruby hashes. You can say `[1, 'a', true].to_json` and get `'[1,"a",true]'` after all. There were issues unpacking JSON-encoded arrays in JavaScript in the past so you'll often see things like `{"0":"x", "1":"y", ...}` instead of a more natural array.